# Windows UWP AesCbcPkcs7 encrypt/decrypt block at a time

Tags: c#, uwp, encryption-symmetric

I have an application that I want to release to the Windows App store. So there is  limited set of APIs that can be used.

It needs to encrypt/decrypt very large amounts of data.
I can find examples on how to load ALL the data into an IBuffer and encrypt/decrypt it. 
I would like to do this on say 8KB chunks at a time. 
I can't figure out how to do that ... 
I start with the IV and the first 8KB chunk of data ...
Do I use the last 16B of the last chunk as the next chunk's IV ?

Comment: No that's in the wrong namespace for an AppStore release. I am trying to figure out how that is implemented ... so I know how to chain Chunks together. Also do I throw out the LAST 16B ?

Comment: What version of Windows 10 are you targeting?

Comment: Any version for now ... I found that: outData = CryptographicEngine.Decrypt(mCipherKey, inData , mIV); would fail if I inData is NOT the full encrypted data (it's size was 4KB out  of approx 5KB of actual data). So it looks like UWP does not support chunk encryption.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to limit yourself to RS3 and above (Fall Creator's Update / 1709) then you can just use .NET cryptography APIs such as [CryptoStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netstandard-2.0) and the related managed crypto APIs.

The WinRT APIs work on all versions of Windows 10 but they're harder to use than the .NET equivalents. You can probably also find more examples of .NET code to learn from.